# ATG CRS changing context root causes raw JSP to display

Tags: atg, endeca

I am working on ATG 10.1.2 with Endeca 3.1.2 with the CRS app. Here is what I've done so far.

wanted to change my context root to /mystore

I changed the contexts in web.xml, application.xml and MANIFEST.MF entry for CommerceReferenceStore, subsequently changed my site configuration for one of the CRS stores to have my custom baseUrl and production URL.

In my case I am not using path based multi-site approach. my baseUrl and production Url are same. If I start my application, all pages are coming fine. However, when I try to browse the category pages (cartridges), the JSP's code is displayed on the browser, they do not compile.

I found some solution on oracle community that I should remove the FORWARD dispatcher from PageFilter from my web.xml, and that should solve the issue. I did that, now the page compiles, but intermittent raw JSPs are displayed along with JSP comments on the browser.

Below threads might give you some context on my issue.

https://community.oracle.com/thread/2508338

https://community.oracle.com/thread/3518254

Has someone tried it and have a solution, please share your inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for posting the answer to this after so long.

This was an issue with Oracle Commerce itself. You should try to get a patch for it from Oracle, if you see this on Oracle Commerce version 10.x

Answer (score 0):

Would suggest you look at your configuration for these components as changing the context root *might* require configuration changes to:

1. `ContentItemToRendererPath` in the ATG [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35318_02/Platform.10-1-1/ATGEndecaIntegrationGuide/html/s0703usingajsprenderertorendercontent01.html)

> *The getRendererPathForContentItem() method returns the web-app relative path of the JSP file used to render the ContentItem.*
>
> `/atg/endeca/servlet/request/NucleusHttpServletRequestProvider` which provides access to the endeca components
>
> `/atg/endeca/assembler/AssemblerPipelineServlet` with a full explanation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35318_02/Platform.10-1-1/ATGEndecaIntegrationGuide/html/s0703usingajsprenderertorendercontent01.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `REQUEST` and `ERROR` as well to the **dispatcher** element.

If you have ...

```
<filter> 
 <filter-name>PageFilter</filter-name> 
 <filter-class>atg.filter.dspjsp.PageFilter</filter-class> 
</filter>

<filter-mapping> 
 <filter-name>PageFilter</filter-name> 
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
 <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher> 
</filter-mapping>
```

then change it to...

```
<filter> 
 <filter-name>PageFilter</filter-name> 
 <filter-class>atg.filter.dspjsp.PageFilter</filter-class> 
</filter>

<filter-mapping> 
  <filter-name>PageFilter</filter-name> 
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
  <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher> 
  <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher> 
  <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher> 
</filter-mapping>
```